# How to find two repetitive elements in a unsorted array on python

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

In this problem I had to find duplicates from 1-N integers in an array given that N+2 size array with N no of integers, below is my code and error it is showing,

Please tell me what is the wrong

```
def find_duplicates(a,n):
    for i in range(n+2):
        if(a[abs(a[i])]>0):
            a[abs(a[i])]= - a[abs(a[i])]
        else:
            print(abs(a[i]), end= " ")
    print("\n")

if __name__ =='__main__':
    cases=int(input())
    for _ in range(cases):
        n=int(input())
        a=list(map(int,input().strip().split()))[:n+2]
        find_duplicates(a,n)
```

error is

Wrong Answer. !!
Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).
The first test case where your code failed:

```
Input:
2
1 1 2 2

Its Correct output is:
1 2

And Your Code's output is:

1 2 4 2 8 15 3 6 2 1 7 6 19 5 7 16 9 2 2 4 35 30 30 2...
```

Comment: I did `find_duplicates([1, 1, 2, 2], 2)` and it gave me `1 2`, so it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Your code already works, you can see the first two outputs are "1 2" which are correct. However, the issue is you print all outputs of testcases in one line which may possibly cause the error. Please try to go to a new line before solving a new testcase as below:

```
if __name__ =='__main__':
    cases=int(input())
    for _ in range(cases):
        n=int(input())
        a=list(map(int,input().strip().split()))[:n+2]
        find_duplicates(a,n)
        print()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.. :) but I forgot to add print("\n") at the end of the function find_duplicates I used before, can't it done using print("\n") because when I was using print("\n) for new line it was again showing error of no output

Comment: Try to use print() instead of print("\n")